# C#, WPF, MVVM: Objects without a view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing a simulation of an insulin pump for an university course. Part of the simulation is an Observable Object `Environment.Time`. The purpose of this object is to notify the Observer Objects in the model when a "time unit" has passed, so it is possible to adjust the speed at which the simulation works.

1. Where do I put (folder structure) this Object, which has no representation in the UI. In fact, its no model, no view and no `viewmodel`, is it?
2. Is it OK, that the "Time" notifies the model, or should it instead notify the `viewModel(s)`?

Comment: Im am sorry. Of course I meant 
2) Is it ok, that the "Time" notifies the model, or should it instead notify the viewModel(s)?

Comment: What is Time? Is it a class that you have made that implements INotifyPropertyChanged? Is it a DateTime property within a class called Environment? Or do you have a class called Environment.Time?

Comment: The [edit] link can be used to fix your question.  Comments shouldn't be used for this purpose.

Comment: 1) who cares. it doesn't matter one bit 2) shouldn't you be modeling how an actual pump does this? Or, if you are not modeling how an actual pump would do this, then who cares? Make something up and go for it.  "My hypothetical pump offers an SDK which updates listeners of status changes via a static event fired at regular intervals." Boom, done, move on.